# React can't read JSON local file value inside component

Tags: json, reactjs

I am trying to read a value from a local json file, I don't get an error but at the same time the value doesn't show when viewing in browser.

I'm using a local json file, but will be swapping for an endpoint later.

Header.js file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import data from './data/app';

export class Header extends Component { 
    render() {

        return (
          <header class="header">
            <div class="header__container">
                <strong>{ data.title }<strong>
            </div>
           </header>
         );
     }
}
export default Header
```

app.json file contents

```
[
    {
        "title": "Document Title",
        "description": "Details about the total number"
     }
]
```

I am then importing in a page in the app using the

```
<Header>
<Header />
```

Comment: `import data from './data/app.json';` and data[0].title

Comment: Also, decide on one approach of using `Header` component, either `<Header/>` or `<Header></Header>`

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi good points mate, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) Be explicit about the extension:

```
import data from './data/app.json';
```

(2) If you want to access `data.title`, the shape of the file must be

```
    {
        "title": "Document Title",
        "description": "Details about the total number"
    }
```

or the code must be

```
data[0].title
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks @AKX, makes total sense now! :)